# Where is stored in wake alarm Date and Time?

Tags: c#, windows-7, bios, motherboard

I want to set the system wake time before shutdown the system. I know, The system can be automatically wake at specific time which is set in the RTC wake alarm time and date at BIOS. I want to do the same as by using C#.net code. When I run this code, the next system wake time needs to set automatically at rtc wake alarm date and time. 
I did this same at Linux system by writing the next system wake time at `/sys/class/rtc/rtc0/wakealarm` location. Like that I would like to do it in windows system also. But I don't know where i want to write the system wake time. When I set the RTC alarm time at BIOS, definitely it will be stored in some file. If I know that location, I may write the next system wake time at that location by using C# code. If you know let me, It is very useful to me.

Comment: It won't be stored in any file because that wouldn't be useful. The BIOS cannot read files.

Comment: Asking the same question again isn't likely to garner much different response than previously. If you're not getting the answers you want, you need to do more work/research yourself and edit your existing question to improve it.

Comment: `When I set the RTC alarm time at BIOS, definitely it will be stored in some file` Doesn't the BIOS just save everything on a tiny chip?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the wakeup time and date is set by BIOS and stored in CMOS area, which is 128byte or 256byte. Besides if you set these in OS and shutdown down PC, what you set will be override by BIOS's code because its routine will be invoked **after** yours(if my recall is correct)